# Stuck on spamming terminal Beginner

Tags: ros, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the book "Learning ROS for robotics programming" and while trying to create a workspace i screwed something up.

I rebooted thinking it would fix the problem, but now i am stuck with a terminal spamming

```
bash: export: `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH/dev/rosbook:/opt/ros/kinetic/share:/opt/ros/kinetic/stacks': not a valid identifier
$: command not found
```

endlessly and i have no idea how to stop it.

As the title indicates i am new to this ROS stuff so bear with me if i sound like a complete moron.

I will do my best to add additional info if required.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241049/stuck-on-spamming-terminal-beginner/) by [KasperJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/27674/kasperj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you forget the '$' in the variable ROS_PACKAGE_PATH? It looks like your Bash startup script has something like this:

```
export PATH=ROS_PACKAGE_PATH/dev/rosbook:$PATH
```

You probably need the '$' before ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

But... I don't know that book, but if the examples are designed to run using rosrun or roslaunch, then you don't need to add the rosbook stuff to the path, as rosrun and roslaunch will search your packages. Did you install the example code according to their directions? (You can't just pick any directory when using ROS with the catkin built tool.)

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2016-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KasperJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/27674/kasperj/) on 2016-08-03**:
[http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/~vlad/teaching/robotics.d/READINGS/Learning%20ROS%20for%20Robotics%20Programming%20[eBook].pdf](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/%7Evlad/teaching/robotics.d/READINGS/Learning%20ROS%20for%20Robotics%20Programming%20%5BeBook%5D.pdf)

chapter 2 page 40 the chapter called "creating our workspace"

It is still spamming the terminal.

**Comment by [KasperJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/27674/kasperj/) on 2016-08-03**:
after i did

```
 $ echo "export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH"~/dev/rosbook:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}" >>
~/.bashrc
$ . ~/.bashrc
```

the next step was to create a ROS package, but the line was stuck with > in front of my command, and so nothing happend when i entered the commands to make a ROS package.

**Comment by [KasperJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/27674/kasperj/) on 2016-08-03**:
thus the reboot.

**Comment by [Sam94](https://answers.ros.org/users/27117/sam94/) on 2016-08-03**:
It sounds like you forgot the ending quotation mark.  That might have caused the '>' to show in front of the command.

**Comment by [KasperJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/27674/kasperj/) on 2016-08-03**:
how do i stop the spamming terminal then?

**Comment by [Sam94](https://answers.ros.org/users/27117/sam94/) on 2016-08-03**:
Try opening your .bashrc file with a text editor and look for the line that the terminal keeps spamming.  Remove that line and restart the ROS tutorial.  Your .bashrc file should be in your home directory, type "ls -a" to see it.